# Datagridview add new column and focus on it

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

Hello sir i am having trouble in focusing my datagridview i have code like this

```
private void dataGridView1_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    DataGridViewColumn col = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
    col.DataPropertyName = "2";
    col.HeaderText = "2".ToString();
    col.Name = "2".ToString();

    dataGridView1.Columns.Add(col);
    mm = e.RowIndex;
    dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex + 1].Selected=true;
}
```

And i want to focus this newly added column cell i have used upper code but its not working its focusing on second row because its a last column of current row i also tried this one

```
private void dataGridView1_ColumnAdded(object sender, DataGridViewColumnEventArgs e)
{
    if (mm != 0)
    { 
        dataGridView1.CurrentCell = dataGridView1.Rows[mm].Cells[e.Column.Index];
        dataGridView1.BeginEdit(true);
        dataGridView1.Rows[mm].Cells[e.Column.Index].Selected = true;
    }
}
```

This really confusing me i have tried all these but still its going to second row first cell what to do in this case?

[Updated]

```
  private void dataGridView1_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
DataGridViewColumn col = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
                                    col.DataPropertyName = "";
                                    col.HeaderText = j.ToString();
                                    col.Name = j.ToString();
                                    dataGridView1.Columns.Add(col);
    }
```

And my code of tried

```
private void dataGridView1_ColumnAdded(object sender, DataGridViewColumnEventArgs e)
        {
            if (mm != 0)
            {
                dataGridView1.ClearSelection();
            dataGridView1.CurrentCell = dataGridView1.Rows[mm].Cells[e.Column.Index];

            dataGridView1.Rows[mm].Cells[e.Column.Index].Selected = true;
            }
        }
```

[image]

***[Updated1]***
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you use is **selecting cell**. To select a column use this code instead:

```
dataGridView1.Columns[columnIndex].Selected = true;
```

Remember to deselect all the columns selected before if you want each column to be selected at a time. You can use some variable to save the last selected column and deselect it when needed.

### UPDATE

Here is the code you should have tried:

```
private void dataGridView1_ColumnAdded(object sender, DataGridViewColumnEventArgs e)
{
   dataGridView1.ClearSelection();
   e.Column.Selected = true;
}
```

Comment: Ok king king let me try first

Comment: @dholakiyaankit could you describe more about how it doesn't work? The column is not selected or some exception is thrown? What's the actual code you tried? If any please update all in your question and I'll try to improve the answer if possible.

Comment: Ok @kingking wait i am updating

Comment: @dholakiyaankit please check your code again, **I didn't see my code in your code**.

Comment: @dholakiyaankit see my update for exactly what you should try, Note that I supposed you want to select the newly added column, if that's not what you want, please clarify it.

Comment: Yaa i tried and I think what i am doing is pressing tab so its going to next row and focuusing on that one it will not working i think